# Could anyone give a human language example which could test ∀x.(px=>q) does euqal to ∃x.px=>q

Tags: logic, quantifiers, first-order-logic

I have problem to understand the equivalence of the following sentence **intuitively** for long time

> ∀x.(px=>q)
>
> ∃x.px=>q

I understand the truth table below does says they are equivalent:

```
p(a) p(B) q  p(a)=>q p(b)=>q (p(a)=>q)&(p(b)=>q) p(a)|p(b)    p(a)|p(b) =>q
 T    F   T      T      T            T               T              T
 F    T   T      T      T            T               T              T
 T    T   T      T      T            T               T              T
 F    F   T      T      T            T               F              T
 T    F   F      F      T            F               T              F 
 F    T   F      T      F            F               T              F
 T    T   F      F      F            F               T              F
 F    F   F      T      T            T               F              T
```

But what i'm looking for is an  **human language example** to verify the validity of the equivalence, so I could understand more **intuitively**, could anyone give a example?

Comment: I don't see why they would be equivalent just because there is an example (your `a` and `b`) for which they are? From what set does `x` come?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one means "there is a px value which implies a q result".

The first one means "for each px value, there is a q result"

This could be the difference between "a driver has a driving licence" and "every drivers must have one".